# GROUP BY foreign_key and date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working with a table called `appointments`, which columns are:

scheduled_at: datetime 
doctor_id: integer
description: text
finished_at: datetime

I want to get a COUNT of all the appointments that have finished grouped by `doctor_id` as well as grouped by a set of date intervals that vary depending on the given set of inputs. The inputs I get are: `from` which is a date and `to` which is also a date.

The first use case I want to solve is splitting the results by months from the given `from` and `to`. So, if I am given `from` = '2018-02-03' and `to` = '2018-10-03' I want to get the COUNT of all the appointments that have finished for each doctor AND for each month from `2018-02` to `2018-10`.

I know how to do the group by doctor_id, but I can't figure out how to also group by those dynamic date intervals.

Here is what I have so far:

`SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM appointments
WHERE finished_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY doctor_id`

I know that if I had the intervals beforehand, I could do as many queries as I have to, so I would end up doing one query for each month, such as:

`SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM appointments
WHERE finished_at IS NOT NULL
AND scheduled_at BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-03-01'
GROUP BY doctor_id`

`SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM appointments
WHERE finished_at IS NOT NULL
AND scheduled_at BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-04-01'
GROUP BY doctor_id`

I am just wondering if there is a way to do that in SQL so I just need to do one query.

Comment: Wrong order. Put GROUP BY after WHERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT doctor_id,
       COUNT(*),
       COUNT(case when scheduled_at BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-03-01' then 1 end),
       COUNT(case when scheduled_at BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-04-01' then 1 end)
FROM appointments
WHERE finished_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY doctor_id
```

Or have a query that `group by` year and month too:

```
SELECT doctor_id, year(scheduled_at), month(scheduled_at), COUNT(*)
FROM appointments
WHERE finished_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY doctor_id, year(scheduled_at), month(scheduled_at)
```

Or, perhaps the ANSI SQL function `EXTRACT` should be used:

```
SELECT doctor_id,
       extract(year from scheduled_at), extract(month from scheduled_at), COUNT(*)
FROM appointments
WHERE finished_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY doctor_id, extract(year from scheduled_at), extract(month from scheduled_at)
```

Comment: I like your first approach and I appreciate all your different options!

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT doctor_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN scheduled_at BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-03-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN scheduled_at BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-04-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    
FROM appointments
WHERE finished_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY doctor_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If your postgres version is 9.4 or greater, using the FILTER predicate should be considered, it is easier to read and slightly more performant than a case statement.

```
SELECT doctor_id,
       COUNT(*) AS total,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE scheduled_at BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-03-01') AS date_feb,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE scheduled_at BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-04-01') AS date_mar
FROM appointments
WHERE finished_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY doctor_id
```